# A-Frame A-Text Mask

Tags: shader, aframe

i can not find any answer about masking a picture with an a-text primitive or other possibilities with a-frame or threejs behind. The bitmap text should be a mask for an underlying image. Somebody told me, it could be solved via shaders https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-text.html#attributes_shader and advised me to read the book of shaders https://thebookofshaders.com with 155 pages foreknowledge! I am not sure if this is the right hint anyway!?

Here you can see the illustrated task position as grafic view:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/MLZjcucfpuqmtinH7

Codepen: http://codepen.w3x.de

Comment: Do you want it like that example (3D text) or what it on the flat text as is? I think you'd have to copy/paste/modify the text shaders from the A-Frame repo to do texture lookups. Should be very possible though since the text is on a plane, makes the UV mapping really easy.

Comment: @ngokevin thanks for your verification. Do you have an example for your suggestion, which i can inject in my codepen example ? I did not find any code example/ advise to solve this webGL challenge via shaders. https://photos.app.goo.gl/MLZjcucfpuqmtinH7

Comment: I wonder if you could use `THREE.TextGeometry` and https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG to subtract the text from a plane or a box? I don't have an example but this sounds easier than using shaders...

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the A-Frame text shader code (remove the module.exports) and register a text shader. Here's the current MSDF shader:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('yourtextshader', {
      schema: {
        alphaTest: {type: 'number', is: 'uniform', default: 0.5},
        color: {type: 'color', is: 'uniform', default: 'white'},
        map: {type: 'map', is: 'uniform'},
        negate: {type: 'boolean', is: 'uniform', default: true},
        opacity: {type: 'number', is: 'uniform', default: 1.0}
      },

      raw: true,

      vertexShader: [
        'attribute vec2 uv;',
        'attribute vec3 position;',
        'uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;',
        'uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;',
        'varying vec2 vUV;',
        'void main(void) {',
        '  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);',
        '  vUV = uv;',
        '}'
      ].join('\n'),

      fragmentShader: [
        '#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives',
        '#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives: enable',
        '#endif',

        'precision highp float;',
        'uniform bool negate;',
        'uniform float alphaTest;',
        'uniform float opacity;',
        'uniform sampler2D map;',
        'uniform vec3 color;',
        'varying vec2 vUV;',

        'float median(float r, float g, float b) {',
        '  return max(min(r, g), min(max(r, g), b));',
        '}',

        // FIXME: Experimentally determined constants.
        '#define BIG_ENOUGH 0.001',
        '#define MODIFIED_ALPHATEST (0.02 * isBigEnough / BIG_ENOUGH)',

        'void main() {',
        '  vec3 sample = texture2D(map, vUV).rgb;',
        '  if (negate) { sample = 1.0 - sample; }',

        '  float sigDist = median(sample.r, sample.g, sample.b) - 0.5;',
        '  float alpha = clamp(sigDist / fwidth(sigDist) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);',
        '  float dscale = 0.353505;',
        '  vec2 duv = dscale * (dFdx(vUV) + dFdy(vUV));',
        '  float isBigEnough = max(abs(duv.x), abs(duv.y));',

        '  // Do modified alpha test.',
        '  if (alpha < alphaTest * MODIFIED_ALPHATEST) { discard; return; }',
        '  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, alpha * opacity);',
        '}'
      ].join('\n')
    });
```

The fragment shader is what computes the color of the text. You get `vUV` which is the UV map for that fragment, telling where to sample in the texture.

What you would need to do to modify this shader. Don't have time to do a full example yet, but...:

1. Accept another parameter of your texture, add to the schema.
2. Pass that texture into the shader (`<a-entity text="shader: yourTextShader; yourTexture: #texture`).
3. Add a uniform for that texture in the fragment shader `uniform sampler2D yourTexture`).
4. Modify the fragment shader to use the texture color instead of the color `gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(yourTexture, vUv), alpha * opacity)`

Comment: Hello Kevin, I've tried to complete your example, but it seems the text primitive needs the extra texture attribute instead of the shader (so we need also register a new primitive)? Instead your 'text-geometry' extension works fine (hint by Don McCurdy) but this as 2D would be nice.